# Available API to set computer sleep and display sleep values in mac os x in a cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am wondering if there is a public api/framework where I can set the computer sleep value and the display sleep value in a cocoa application on mac os x? I am interested in making a utility application that will place an icon in the menu bar, allow the user to create different power option settings and what not.

I am not interested in using any private frameworks as I want to develop this application for the Mac App Store.

I always find myself changing the energy saver and screen saver values when i'm a home and when I wont be at home. Because I use Carbonite, I always leave my machine running. When I'm at home, I like the screen saver to come on after so many minutes, but when I away, like when I'm at work or a sleep at night, I prefer the screen saver to be off and the screen to sleep after one minute of inactivity. It would be nice to not have to go into system preferences all the time to do this. Any one else agree?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

You can create a wrapper around the [pmset](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) utility, which allows you to change the power management settings on the command line, using either `system()` or (better) an [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003745).